# How to instantly refresh DataGridView after executing SQL Command

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to refresh the `DataGridView` right after executing an `SQL` Command, so when the user presses the update button all details must change as well as the DataGridView. This is my code and I don't know where to add this function.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click, Button5.Click
    Try
        Dim a As String

        cn.Open()

        Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        cmd = New SqlCommand("update Addemployees set Fname= '" & TextBox1.Text & "', Lname= '" & TextBox3.Text & "', ID= '" & TextBox4.Text & "', CIN= '" & TextBox2.Text & "', phone= '" & TextBox6.Text & "', Email= '" & TextBox5.Text & "', fromD= '" & TextBox8.Text & "', toD= '" & TextBox7.Text & "' where ID='" & ComboBox1.Text & "' ", cn)

        cmd.Connection = cn
        a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Process successful!", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        cn.Close()

    Catch
        MessageBox.Show("Error!", "exit", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        cn.Dispose()
    End Try
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox3.Clear()
    TextBox4.Clear()
    TextBox5.Clear()
    TextBox6.Clear()
    TextBox7.Clear()
    TextBox8.Clear()
    DateTimePicker2 = Nothing
    DateTimePicker1 = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: A) Never ever concat strings to make SQL - it is tedious, dangerous, hard to read and error prone.  Use SQL parameters,  B) There is nothing there relating to a DGV, but if you use a DataSource, you can do an actual refresh easily

Comment: Thank you very much that was really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a Method or a Function that displays data in the DATAGRIDVIEW and then call the method whenever you add/delete/update just be sure to add/delete/update first before calling the method or function

```
Sub display()
    Dim temp As Double = 0
    Dim lt As String = "select id as ID, vlname as Last, vfname as First, 
                vmname as Middle, vgnd as Gender, vdob as Birthday, iage as 
                Age, vcourse as Course from tbreg where vlname Like '" + 
                tbsearch.Text + "%' or vfname Like '" + tbsearch.Text + "%' 
                order by vlname asc" 
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(lt, con)
    con.Open()

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "tbreg")
    da.Dispose()
    dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Just add the display() method right after saving/deleting/updating your database

'updating and then refreshing the datagridview right after doing the update you 
             just have to call the method

```
Dim supdate As String = "Update tbuser set vname = '" & tbname.Text & "', 
                     vemail = '" & tbemail.Text & "', vuser = '" & 
                     tbuser.Text & "', vpass = '" & tbpass.Text & "' where 
                      vid = '" & dgv.SelectedCells(0).Value & "'"

Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(supdate, con)
con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("Successfully Updated!!!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, 
                       "System COnfirmed!")
con.Close()
'display method here!
display()
```

Comment: Thank you i will try this and reply

Comment: Glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing here. After the save is successful, call the procedure you used to view the contents in `DataGridView` This works.

I will show you my example:

I have a student attendance adding/viewing form. There is a `TabControl` with two tabs, one for adding and another for viewing.

In the add tab, there is a button which submits the attendance of students to a database. After the submission is done, I then show a message like this:

```
Private Sub SubmitBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SubmitBtn.Click
 '{rest of the code}
 'add attendance success
    MsgBox("Attendance added for " & yyyy_txt.Text & "/" & mm_txt.Text & "/" & dd_txt.Text, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
End Sub
```

In the view tab, there are few option on how the user wants to see the attendance record which is done by selecting option from `ComboBoxes` and then clicking the `SearchBtn` button.

```
 'search attendance
Private Sub SearchBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchBtn.Click
    If SelectClass2.Text = "" Or SearchType.Text = "" Or SearchKey.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Select search options to continue", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    Else
        If SearchType.Text = "By Date" Then
            'search by date, call procedure 'displayatt'
            Dim xyz As String = SearchKey.Text.Substring(0, 5)
            displayatt(SearchKey.Text, SelectClass2.Text, String.Format("YYYY/MM/DD", xyz), True)
        Else
            'search by student, call procedure 'displayatt'
            displayatt(SearchKey.Text.Substring(3, SearchType.Text.Length - 3), SelectClass2.Text, SearchKey.Text.Substring(0, 5), False)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Well, you can update the `DataGridView1` contents by calling the procedure which shows the contents. In my case, I would add `SearchBtn_Click(SearchBtn, Nothing)` right after showing the messagebox about the completion of adding the attendance.   Then it will look like this:

```
Private Sub SubmitBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SubmitBtn.Click
 '{rest of the code}
 'add attendance success
    MsgBox("Attendance added for " & yyyy_txt.Text & "/" & mm_txt.Text & "/" & dd_txt.Text, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    SearchBtn_Click(SearchBtn, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Try it. :)

Comment: i have tried this it is really helpful thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, don't forget the vote the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Use this class for Microsoft SQL and see the LoadDB for how to use it. Also don't hardcode you query like you did. Someone using your app could do SQL injection and drop your tables. Use params like I showed you. You probably also want to update only a specific record so add the WHERE instruction in your query

```
Sub LoadDB
dim xdb as new dbMSSQL
dim SQLQuery as String = "update Addemployees set fname=@colfname, lname=@collanme, etc WEHRE ID=@colID"

xdb.addparam("@colid",RecordID)
xdb.addparam("@colfname",textbox1.text)
xdb.addparam("@collname",textbox2.text)
.......

xdb.execquery(Sqlquery)
datagridview1.datasource=xdb.dbdt
end sub



    Imports System.Data.SqlClient



    Public Class dbMSSQL
        ' CREATE YOUR DB CONNECTION
        Public SQLSource As String = "Data Source=[yourcomputer]\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=True"




        Private DBCon As New SqlConnection(SQLSource)
        'Private DBCon As New MySqlConnection(SQLSource)

        ' PREPARE DB COMMAND
        Private DBCmd As SqlCommand

        ' DB DATA
        Public DBDA As SqlDataAdapter
        Public DBDT As DataTable

        ' QUERY PARAMETERS
        Public Params As New List(Of SqlParameter)

        ' QUERY STATISTICS
        Public RecordCount As Integer
        Public Exception As String

        Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)
            ' RESET QUERY STATS
            RecordCount = 0
            Exception = ""


            Try
                ' OPEN A CONNECTION
                DBCon.Open()

                ' CREATE DB COMMAND
                DBCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, DBCon)

                ' LOAD PARAMS INTO DB COMMAND
                Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))

                ' CLEAR PARAMS LIST
                Params.Clear()

                ' EXECUTE COMMAND & FILL DATATABLE

                DBDT = New DataTable
                DBDA = New SqlDataAdapter(DBCmd)
                RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Exception = ex.Message
            End Try


            ' CLOSE YOUR CONNECTION
            If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
        End Sub

        ' INCLUDE QUERY & COMMAND PARAMETERS
        Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
            Dim NewParam As New SqlParameter(Name, Value)
            Params.Add(NewParam)
        End Sub

    End Class
```

here actual code from a project

```
   Dim xDB As New mysql
    xDB.AddParam("@colisconnected", 1)
    xDB.AddParam("@colcpuid", CPUid)
    xDB.AddParam("@colfwuid", userId)
    xDB.ExecQuery("UPDATE clients.computerinfo SET isconnected=@colisconnected WHERE (cpuid=@colcpuid) and (customerid=@colfwuid)")
```

Comment: you should name you table employees instead. And to view your entire table SQLQuery="SELECT * from employess". SQL Express will only work locally and limitations on the size of your DB will be better. You need your app to work over a network consider using mysql. I can supply you a class that works the same way as the MSSQL class.

Comment: that's wonderful. i really appreciate your advice thank you very much. i will  try the code and reply.

Comment: @OuallaWalid I use this class all the time.  I added some feature to mine like getrecord(Table,ID) so I don't have to re-write lines of code all the time.